# You are not authorized to perform the task you are attempting. You may need to be assigned additional permissions in PROD

Tags: sitecore-cli

When we are trying to deploy the serialized items into our production cm through Sitecore CLI using devops pipeline but getting the below error: "You are not authorized to perform the task you are attempting. You may need to be assigned additional permissions."

As mentioned in another thread, I don't want to make ***"requireAuthentication"*** **false**. Is there any other alternative way?

Comment: Having a very similar issue here. Our dev and qa environments are fine, but the newly stood up prod environment is showing this same error. Did you come to a resolution on this that you may be able to share? Thanks.

Comment: @Mark We found out, there was a custom pipeline code written for userBuilder which was causing the issue. once we have removed it, started working.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing a similar issue. And by troubleshooting it, I found that the **identityServerAuthority** value in `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config` was wrong. Correcting it resolved the issue.